# How to test if there is an active network connection in powershell?

Tags: powershell, networking, windows-10

I want part of my script to only run if the computer has any established network connection. It can be wifi, ethernet, anything that's not virtual. I don't need full internet, just LAN.

This is all for Windows 10 64bit, and this script is part of a larger script I'm going to use for deploying some machines.

Note: I'm definitely a powershell noob, I'm not very familiar with it. Honestly I'm still a noob with programming and scripting in general, but powershell especially.

I think I need some function to check each network adapter individually, but I'm not sure how to do that in powershell.

```bsh
if (Get-NetAdapter -Name "*" -Physical == "Up") {
    Write-Host "Pass"
}
else {
    Write-Host "Fail"
}
```

I hoped my code would maybe check each option in the list of `Get-NetAdapter`, but it gave an error on the `==` argument, it can't find a positional parameter that accepts it. I also tried `=` which gave the same error.

Comment: try -eq instead :)

Comment: The equality comparison operator in PowerShell is `-eq`, not `==`. Also, you need to put the command in parentheses, otherwise `-eq` would be parsed as a parameter to `Get-NetAdapter`.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Can't believe I didn't think to look up that. However doesn't fully solve my problem, how do I compare the array of network adapters to see if one has the status "Up"?

Comment: with foreach. I write an example-code, give me a minute

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Examplecode to check an array of network adapter

```
$networkavailable = $false;
foreach ($adapter in Get-NetAdapter){
  if ($adapter.status -eq "Up"){$networkavailable = $true; break;}
}
```

Comment: This worked, thanks. But what is the `break;` for? The code appears to work fine without it.

Comment: It breaks the loop after the first hit. Without it i will loop through every network connection, even if it already found one with status 'up'. Unless you don't have thousands of network connections, there should no measurable difference in runningtime without it.

Answer (score 2):

You could check for a network adapter with a status of 'Up', and then use the result for your condition...

```
if (Get-NetAdapter | Where-Object {$_.Status -eq 'Up'}) {

    #do something

}

else {

    #do something else

}
```